# How to find a boolean in a list with a string in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a debug menu for my game with all the boolean in my GameManager exposed in a in-game UI for my non-programmer teammates.

I am trying to find a bool in a list with a string and I’m not sure how to do it.

This is my pseudocode:

```
[SerializeField] string myBoolName;

private void LookForBool()    
{
    foreach (var bolean in debugMenu.gameManagerBoolList)
    {
        if (debugMenu.gameManagerBoolList.Contains(bolean))
        {
            myBoolName = bolean;
        }
    }
  
}

public void SwitchBoolWithToggle() //Will be called in a UI toggle
{
    switch (toggle.isOn)
    {
        case true:
            myBoolName = true;
            break;
        case false:
            myBoolName = false;
            break;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do this? I’m still consider myself a beginner.

Thank you!

Comment: Your current if-condition will always evaluate to true: iterating over a collection to check if it contains it's own items is pretty redundant. What exactly are you trying to do? And what type is gameManagerBoolList? And why would you store a boolean as string, you shouldn't do that.

Comment: You say that you have a list that contains booleans. While the list works with index and has nothing to do with string. How did you make this list?

Comment: You can also simplify your SwitchBoolWithToggle method using an XOR: `public void SwitchBoolWithToggle() => myBoolName ^= true;`. This will toggle your field every time you call the method.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear what exactly you are trying to do here.

If you iterate over

```
foreach (var bolean in debugMenu.gameManagerBoolList)
```

then it should be quite obvious that each and every of these `bolean` elements of `debugMenu.gameManagerBoolList` are of course contained by that `debugMenu.gameManagerBoolList`.

---

Why not rather use a dictionary `Dictionary<string, bool>` or maybe even use an `enum` as key so you could even simply select it via the Inspector ad avoid any typos.

The default drawer of Unity for enums in the Inspector is a simple dropdown field ;)

I would do something like this

```
public enum AvailableBools
{
    SomeKey,
    SomeOtherKey,
    ...
}
```

and then in your manager class

```
private readonly Dictionary<AvailableBools, bool> bools = new Dictionary<AvailableBools, bool>();
public IDictionary<AvailableBools, bool> Bools => bools;

private void Awake()
{
    foreach(var key in (AvailableBools[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(AvailableBools)))
    {
        // or true depending on your desired default state
        bools[key] = false;
    }
}
```

There are fancy assets like e.g. [SerializableDictionary](https://github.com/azixMcAze/Unity-SerializableDictionary) which you could use for simply initializing the default values via the Inspector if they have different initial values

```
// might not be required anymore in newer Unity versions as generic classes can now be serialized
[Serializable]
public class AvailablBoolsDictionary : SerializableDictionary<AvailableBools, bool>{}

[SerializeField] private AvailablBoolsDictionary bools;
public IDictionary<AvailableBools, bool> Bools => bools;
```

For your specific use case I once even made a variant of that specific for an enum and pre-initialize all the enum value fields

[EnumMap](https://gist.github.com/der-hugo/51f8f1c410fbec5e0910ad3a04bedb32) which you use quite similar:

```
[SerializeField] private EnumMap<AvailableBools, bool> bools;
public EnumMap<AvailableBools, bool> Bools => bools;
```

in newer Unity versions it is not required anymore to have a `[Serializable]` wrapper class as generics can now be serialized as well.

[image]

(one known issue - I was too lazy so far - when the enum itself is changed afterwards the changes are not reflected in the map since it already is serialized - but you could extend the serialization to cover that case)

and then in your class rather simply do e.g.

```
[SerializeField] AvailableBools myBool;


public void OnValuChanged(bool isOn)
{
    debugMenu.Bools[myBool] = isOn;
}
```

Comment: If op really wants to do this, I recommend buying [Odin Inspector](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/odin-inspector-and-serializer-89041#description) right now, as this technique takes more than €50 euros to complete. :)

Comment: @KiynL not really ^^ as said above are links to assets that can do that without any issue ... as fallback even a simple list of key value pairs could do without fancy drawer. Note that Odin is cool and all (I really mean that) but because it is so powerful it also introduces a lot of unnecessary overhead and some serialization side effects you will need to have in mind

Comment: I was just saying, because nobody knows what he's doing. And you were making a lot of suggestions.

Comment: No offense... ;)

Answer (score -1):

I recommend the method here that you do not need any list at all, just define booleans with their own names.

```cs
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool loopAnimation;
    public bool attackTwice;
    public bool gameIsOver;

    public string myBoolName = "loopAnimation"; // find boolean

///...
}
```

Next, to catch boolean by name, use the following commands that monitor field information.

```cs
private void OnValidate()
{
    foreach (var fieldInfo in typeof(Test).GetFields())
    {
        if (fieldInfo.FieldType == typeof(bool) && fieldInfo.Name == myBoolName)
        {
            Debug.Log(fieldInfo.Name+": "+fieldInfo.GetValue(this)); // loopAnimation: true
        }
    }
}
```

---

The following command will also help to toggle booleans.

```cs
private void ToggleByName(string boolName)
{
    foreach (var fieldInfo in typeof(Test).GetFields())
    {
        if (fieldInfo.FieldType == typeof(bool) && fieldInfo.Name == boolName)
        {
            fieldInfo.SetValue(this, ! (bool) fieldInfo.GetValue(this));
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you are looking for a dictionary to solve the problem, the following solution will automatically create a dictionary that makes it much easier to get variables.

```cs
private Dictionary<string, bool> boolDict;

private void Start()
{
    foreach (var fieldInfo in typeof(Test).GetFields())
    {
        if (fieldInfo.FieldType == typeof(bool) && fieldInfo.Name == myBoolName)
        {
            boolDict.Add(fieldInfo.Name, (bool) fieldInfo.GetValue(this));
        }
    }
}
```

Getting variables is very simple and optimized.

```cs
public void Update() => Debug.Log(boolDict[myBoolName]);
```

Keep in mind that in order for your dictionary to be identical to variables during runtime, you need to set both at the same time.

```cs
loopAnimation = true;
boolDict[nameof(loopAnimation)] = true;
```

Comment: I would totally **not** ever `recommend` Reflection if there is any other available option to avoid it ;) Reflection is the very last resort if there really is no other way at all

Comment: @derHugo Defining a dictionary requires another workflow, and if the project has going on, implementing your proposed method may be time consuming and complicated. But if OP really intends to do so, I recommend filling your dictionary with reflection and then getting the information. It must also follow the sync rule for set, or write it to the property. Certainly 2022 systems can handle this code and there is no need to worry.

Comment: to me it sounds like way more refactoring to everywhere set both fields and dictionary value whenever changing than rather once change you accesses to use a single dictionary access point rather than individual fields ;) Refactor to correct data structure imho goes over expensive runtime and maintenance .. imagine just forgetting to sync at one place and debug for hours until you find it ;)